# Rails 7 + MariaDB: Add a missing uniqueness constraint to the column of a belongs_to reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mariadb, foreign-keys, unique-index

Assuming `Cancellation` `belongs_to` `Subscription` and the DB migration has been performed with a regular Rails 7 `add_reference` statement, yielding the following DB situation:

- There is a column `cancellations.subscription_id`
- There is an index `index_cancellations_on_subscription_id`
- There is a foreign key constraint from cancellations to subscriptions

The goal is to add a uniqueness constraint to the index, in order to ensure that no two cancellations can belong to the same subscription.

There is existing data and we do not want to destroy it.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not (yet) have a `change_index` method. To add the uniqueness constraint, the index must be deleted and re-created. However it cannot be deleted because it is needed for the foreign key. For this reason, the foreign key must be deleted first.

The migration looks as follows:

```rb
class AddUniquenessConstraintToSubscriptionCancellations < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :cancellations, :subscriptions
    remove_index :cancellations, :subscription_id
    add_index :cancellations, subscription_id, unique: true
    add_foreign_key :cancellations, :subscriptions
  end
end
```

This does not alter the column's contents, so the data is safe. The migration will fail if there are any duplicates, so make sure to clean your data first.